# Problem in creaating dialog Box inside Fragment (Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

first time asking question here hope ill get an answer :)
Im new to Kotlin, i am programming in C++ for 3+ years now and just now i moved to mobile applications
so my question is:
im trying to create dialog box inside fragment that allows the user to insert free field text.
when he click the plus button it should open dialog box with free field text area that allow him to insert text then to click "Add" or "Cancel"
when i do run the program all i see in the dialog box is the buttons "Add" and "Cancel" but i cant see the text field bar itself.

but when i change the view from fragment_view to dialog_view i do see the text field bar.
(i hope i was clear in my problem explanation)
this is my fragment(fragment_shopping_list) code:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shopping_list, container, false)
        val addItem_button = view.findViewById<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab_shoppiglist)
        addItem_button.setOnClickListener {
            val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            val tempView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_shoppinglist,null )
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Add"){ _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->

            }
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel"){ _: DialogInterface, _: Int->

            }
            dialog.show()

        }

        return view
    }
```

and this is my dialog (dialog_shoppinglist) code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_Itemlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val dialog = context?.let { AlertDialog.Builder(it) }
dialog?.setView(R.layout.dialog_shoppinglist)
dialog?.setPositiveButton("Add"){ _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
}
dialog?.setNegativeButton("Cancel"){ _: DialogInterface, _: Int->
}
dialog?.show()
```

Comment: please add a minimum description of what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val tempView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_shoppinglist, null)
val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
    .setPositiveButton("Add"){ _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->

    }.setNegativeButton("Cancel"){ _: DialogInterface, _: Int->

    }.create()

dialog.show()
dialog.window!!.setContentView(tempView)
// the following is optional
dialog.window!!.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE)
dialog.window!!.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM)
```

Add this in onClick of button:

```
val text = tempView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_Itemlist).text.toString
```

And you can get the text you have input in the dialog.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.
i did tried your solution and the compiler did not recognize dialog.window!! but i noticed that i didnt add dialog.setView() method
now that i added dialog.setView method i do see the text field bar in my dialog box.
thank you again for your attention good website i will use this community to consult and solve more problems in the future ty, and have a nice day

Comment: @sean  I forgot this:  val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create()